# Embed video from USB webcam into web page using ffserver and ffmpeg

Tags: http, video, stream

I need to stream images from a USB webcam to a webpage on my embedded system. The operating system used is Linux.

I successfully installed **ffserver** and **ffmpeg**, and also **mplayer**.
This is my **/etc/ffserver.conf** (it's not definitive, I am just testing it):

```
# Port on which the server is listening. You must select a different
# port from your standard HTTP web server if it is running on the same
# computer.
Port 8090

# Address on which the server is bound. Only useful if you have
# several network interfaces.
BindAddress 0.0.0.0

# Number of simultaneous HTTP connections that can be handled. It has
# to be defined *before* the MaxClients parameter, since it defines the
# MaxClients maximum limit.
MaxHTTPConnections 2

# Number of simultaneous requests that can be handled. Since FFServer
# is very fast, it is more likely that you will want to leave this high
# and use MaxBandwidth, below.
MaxClients 2

# This the maximum amount of kbit/sec that you are prepared to
# consume when streaming to clients.
MaxBandwidth 1000

# Access log file (uses standard Apache log file format)
# '-' is the standard output.
CustomLog -

# Suppress that if you want to launch ffserver as a daemon.
NoDaemon

<Feed feed1.ffm>
    File /tmp/feed1.ffm #when remarked, no file is beeing created and the stream keeps working!!
    FileMaxSize 200K
       # Only allow connections from localhost to the feed.
       ACL allow 127.0.0.1
    # the output stream format - SWF = flash
    Format swf
    # this must match the ffmpeg -r argument
    VideoFrameRate 5
    # another quality tweak
    VideoBitRate 320
    # quality ranges - 1-31 (1 = best, 31 = worst)
    VideoQMin 1
    VideoQMax 3
    VideoSize 640x480
    # wecams don't have audio
    NoAudio
</Stream>

# FLV output - good for streaming
<Stream test.flv>
    # the source feed
    Feed feed1.ffm
    # the output stream format - FLV = FLash Video
    Format flv
    VideoCodec flv
    # this must match the ffmpeg -r argument
    VideoFrameRate 5
    # another quality tweak
    VideoBitRate 320
    # quality ranges - 1-31 (1 = best, 31 = worst)
    VideoQMin 1
    VideoQMax 3
    VideoSize 640x480
    # wecams don't have audio
    NoAudio
</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
    Format status
</Stream>

<Redirect index.html>
    # credits!
    URL http://ffmpeg.sourceforge.net/
</Redirect>
```

From the shell I can execute:

```
# ffserver -f /etc/ffserver.conf
```

and

```
# ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -r 5 -i /dev/video0 http://127.0.0.1:8090/test.flv
```

No errors are reported during the execution. Sounds good but maybe it's not OK at all.

Then, in the webpage, I wrote this simple code:

```
<video controls>
   <source src="http://127.0.0.1:8090/test.flv">
</video>
```

I read on another thread here on stack overflow (I lost the link) that this code should be enough.. But it's not working for me.

But I can see the file **/tmp/feed1.ffm** has been created, so I think I can use this stream to show the camera images on my webpage. Am I right ?

What it the simplest solution ? 
Thank you.

**EDIT**

I allowed the connections into the ffserver's configuration file:

```
<Feed feed1.ffm>
        File /tmp/feed1.ffm #when remarked, no file is beeing created and the stream keeps working!!
        FileMaxSize 200K
       ACL allow 127.0.0.1
       ACL allow localhost
       ACL allow 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.10   
</Feed>
```

But still does not work.

Comment: Hi simo-zz. It's been a while since your question. Did you mange to get this to work? If so, I'd be interested to know how you did it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -r 5 -i /dev/video0
> http://127.0.0.1:8090/test.flv
> ```

As described in [the documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html#How-do-I-make-it-work_003f), you should stream to the feed1.ffm file, not to the test.flv file. ffmpeg -> ffserver communication is the ffm file, and ffserver -> webbrowser communication is the .flv file.

Comment: OK, you are right. But in the browser I get the error `GET http://127.0.0.1:8090/test.swf net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. And I have allowed the connections into the ffserver.conf file.

Comment: The stream has the extension .flv, not .swf, in your ffserver.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I think HTML doesn't like the pseudo files like pipes or .ffm :)

Maybe you could use the `<embed>`tag from HTML5.

```
<embed type="video/flv" src="http://127.0.0.1:8090/test.flv" width="320" height="240">
```

Or however you want to set the size.